# Entity Framework - How to pass Include off to method caller?

Tags: entity-framework

I have a method that calls a DbSet from an Entity Framework database:

```
    public static List<CostEntryVM> ToViewModelList(this DbSet<CostEntry> CostEntrys, Expression<Func<CostEntry, bool>> query) {

        return AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<List<CostEntry>, List<CostEntryVM>>(
              CostEntrys
                .Include(x => x.Job)
                .Include(x => x.User)
                .Where(query)
                .ToList());
    }
```

To use this I can then do for example:

```
CostEntrys.ToViewModelList(x => x.Active == true);
```

I want to also be able to call:

```
        CostEntrys.ToViewModelList(x => x.Include(y => y.Job).Include(y.User), x => x.Active == true);
```

I can't for the life of me figure out how the method signature should look or how I would then apply that to the DbSet.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to change the extension method to:

```
public static List<CostEntryVM> ToViewModelList(
        this DbSet<CostEntry> CostEntrys, 
        Expression<Func<CostEntry, bool>> query,
        Func<IQueryable<CostEntry>, IQueryable<CostEntry>> func)
{
    // Adding the predicate query
    IQueryable<CostEntry> queryable = CostEntrys.Where(query);

    // Adding include paths
    IQueryable<CostEntry> queryableWithFetch = func(queryable);

    // Executing the query and map it to the view model object
    return AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<List<CostEntry>, List<CostEntryVM>>(
            queryableWithFetch.ToList());
}
```

And then you can call it:

```
CostEntrys.ToViewModelList(
        x => x.Active == true, 
        x => x.Include(y => y.Job).Include(y.User));
```